# Helm Dependency Update not working from ansible shell

Tags: ansible, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to run `helm dependency update charts/` from Ansible shell module, but its throwing error

> Error: XYZ chart not found in repo https://abc/123

However, when i am running same command manually it is working.
I am using same user in both the case.

```
shell: helm dependency update charts/
```

Comment: You may benefit from using [`helm --debug`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/#options) in order to see what assumption you have made. Without knowing more, I'd _guess_ your user has some credentials that the ansible playbook does not have, like an environment variable, but given that your question is basically "it didn't work," we're left to just take wild guesses

Answer (score 0):

In Ansible shell module i was running

```
shell: |
   helm repo update
   helm dependency update ....
```

While debugging i found helm repo was not updated in ~/.cache/helm/repo/repo_name-charts.txt
Then after adding some sleep after helm repo update command, next command worked.

```
 shell: |
       helm repo update
       sleep 40
       helm dependency update ....
```

This is not convincing but for me it worked. Seems helm repo update command updates repo asynchronously.